# Django tag showing errors in html

Tags: html, css, django, visual-studio-code

I have this block of code in my django project:

```
<div class="avatar-preview">
    <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url({{ request.user.img_url }});"></div>
</div>
```

In Virtual Studio Code, it returns these errors:
[VSCODE PROBLEMS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGGD4.png)

But it's actually working, I mean, like the 'syntax' is wrong but the code works, the image is displayed correctly. How can I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Show your css for the html .. the error might be there

Comment: The problem is the {{request.user.img_url}} because when I delete it, everything goes back to normal @Amit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url({{ request.user.img_url }})` the `{{ request.user.img_url }}` needs to be wrapped in `''`

```
<div class="avatar-preview">
    <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('{{ request.user.img_url }}');"></div>
</div>
```